# how to obtain same date result on different servers

Tags: php, date, timezone

```
<?php

//                            viper-7            phpfiddle
fdate(1346976000);       // Fri 2012-09-07     Thu 2012-09-06
fdate(1348704000);       // Thu 2012-09-27     Wed 2012-09-26
fdate(time());           // see yourself

function fDate($what){echo date('D Y-m-d',$what).'<br>';}

?>
```

test links
http://codepad.viper-7.com/d4tUES
http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/zdx-u10

What do I  need to set up in order to have the same results on any server?
Thanks

I am sure is a matter of time zone, but I do not know how to be aware of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [default timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Set it to UTC or GMT and you can use it as a basis for all your servers

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); 

fdate(time());  // will return the UTC time
```

Answer (score 2):

use gmdate to return gmt time

```
function fDate($what){echo gmdate('D Y-m-d',$what).'<br>';}
```

see if you still have issues.

Answer (score 1):

Include `date_default_timezone_set` at the beginning of your script based on your desired timezone.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
?>
```

[List of Supported Timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)